# Is it possible to set realtime database value using setValue() function in the adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set the value of the realtime database using setValue() function. I don't know it works or not, but I have seen many using setValue() function in the model but they never used it. But I am trying to implement in my code.

here is my adapter code:-

```
class PostsAdapter(
    private var mContext: Context,
    private var mPosts: List<PostsModel>,
    private var isFragmnet: Boolean = false
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PostsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.rv_posts_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val post = mPosts[position]

        val statusAvailable = post.getStatus()

        if (statusAvailable == "Inactive") {
            holder.status.text = mContext.resources.getString(R.string.activate)

            holder.activate.setOnClickListener {
                post.setStatus("Active")
            }
        }else {
            holder.status.text = mContext.resources.getString(R.string.deactivate)

            holder.activate.setOnClickListener {
                post.setStatus("Inactive")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mPosts.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View)  : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        var imageUrl: ImageView? = itemView.postsImage
        var status: TextView = itemView.changeStatus
        var activate: CardView = itemView.activateBtn

    }
}
```

here is my model code:-

```
class PostsModel {
    private var imageURL: String = ""
    private var status: String = ""

    constructor()

    constructor(
        imageURL: String,
        status: String
    ){
        this.imageURL = imageURL
        this.status = status
    }


    fun getImageURL(): String {
        return imageURL
    }

    fun getStatus(): String {
        return status
    }

    fun setStatus(status: String) {
        this.status = status
    }
}
```

I am not sure whether it really works or not. I know it is possible to do using HashMap by updating children but I want to know whether this setValue() function really works or not.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the problem, and don't see any calls to `setValue` in the code you shared. If you step through this code in a debugger line by line, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I mean setStatus() function in my code. To generalise I used term setValue() function. I have seen some codes on some websites or YouTube channels, where they use this type of set function to set any particular value.

Comment: I'm still not clear what the problem is with the code you shared, and since it doesn't call the Firebase API anywhere it is really hard to help. What isn't working about your `setStatus` call?

Comment: Like we don't have to call firebase API to get the value. I was trying to set the value without calling Firebase API.